# How do I get the key in array of objects using .map()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

So here I have an array like this

```
[{"facebook":"https://facebook.com"}, {"instagram":"https://instagram.com"}]
```

And now I want to display the key as an Icon name and the value as href link.

```
socials.map((social, index) => { 
    return(
        <View key={index}>
             <Icon name={social.facebook} onPress={() => {}} />
        </View>
    ); 
})
```

How do I assign the key to icon name without selecting the specific key name ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `socials` is your initial data array, then I would do following:

```
socials.map((social, index) =>
    (
        <View key={index}>
             <Icon name={Object.keys(social)[0]} onPress={() => {}} />
        </View>
    )
)
```

Comment: Thanks ! It works.

Answer (score 3):

Use `Object.keys()` -

```js
let data = [{"facebook":"https://facebook.com"}, {"instagram":"https://instagram.com"}]

data.forEach(social => console.log(Object.keys(social)[0]));
```

Here, I'm using `.forEach()` instead of `.map()` just to log the key's name, but the idea is the same with `.map()`.

Comment: `[{"facebook":"https://facebook.com"}, {"instagram":"https://instagram.com"}].map(Object.keys).map(String)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) with `map` method.Object.keys return an array of it's own properties. So `Object.keys(item)[0]` will give the key from each object.

```js
var social = [{
  "facebook": "https://facebook.com"
}, {
  "instagram": "https://instagram.com"
}]
var x = social.map(function(item) {
  return Object.keys(item)[0]
})
console.log(x)
```